# How to Use UISearchBar for Custom Cells in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm populating my tableview from an array. And this array is created by SQLite query.
So in my array, I have objects from my user-defined class.
And I use custom cells in my table. Like `object.name` in one layer, `object.id` near this layer.
So far everything's good. But if I try to use UISearchBar, how will I re-populate my table?

This is the code I create my table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SpeakersCell";

    SpeakersCell *cell = (SpeakersCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SpeakersCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SpeakersCell class]]) {
                cell = (SpeakersCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Set up the cell
    ProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Speaker *speakerObject = (Speaker *)[appDelegate.speakers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lblSpeakerName.text = speaker.speakerName;
    cell.lblSpeakerCity.text = speaker.speakerCity;
    return cell;
}
```

When I add a search bar and define `searchBar textDidChange` event, I successfully get items that contains the key letters. But I can't re-populate my table because I only have searched items' names.

Tutorials I got help from are built on default cells and the datasource of tableview is NSString array. But my array is NSObject array, this is my problem.

I consider getting indexes of searched items but how can I use these values either? Do you have any idea or any related link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at Bobgreen's blog, his tutorial helped me quite a lot.

http://www.cocoabob.net/?p=67

Check his delegeate function for UISearchDisplayController (which I guess you might want to use?)

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
   [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects];
    for (Product *product in listContent)
  {
    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [product.type isEqualToString:scope])
     {
        NSComparisonResult result = [product.name compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
         [self.filteredListContent addObject:product];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

He has an array of NSObject's (`product`) there which he loops thru. Each time a result matches the search string he puts the value in an second array called `filteredListContent` and he'll show upp the filtered content. Works like a charm for me.

Comment: Well I realized that it's easier with UISearchDisplayContoller but I couldn't find a straight tutorial. I'll try that and inform here about results. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I followed another way for some reason but thanks for the answer again.

Comment: I better write an article to my personal homepage, because it took much time to understand and collect all together. Then I might share the link by editing my post. If you yourself need it, I can send it to you of course.

Comment: No, I don't need it, but it would be great to know how you solved it. You know, for future references off course and others whom might have the same problem here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Of course, like I said, I'll edit the post when I finish the article and add the link. Thank you.

Comment: And here it is, 2013. Have you finished your article yet? Where's the post?